# reading geojson with readOGR

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis, rgdal

I am attempting to load some ggvis mapping code via this git: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggvis-maps

The code is returning errors on line 27 in the server file:

```
Warning: Error in ogrInfo: Cannot open data source
Stack trace (innermost first):
41: ogrInfo
40: withCallingHandlers
39: suppressMessages
38: readOGR
37: server [\ggvis-maps-master/server.R#27]
 1: runApp
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = 
use_iconv,  : 
Cannot open data source
```

I've used path.expand and a few other solutions I found, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code that is resulting in this error

Comment: `shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
.....
  maine <- readOGR(dsn="/data/maine.geojson", layer="OGRGeoJSON")`

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue too. Except, I am trying to embed a leaflet chloropleth map in a Shiny app, and it worked for me locally, but not when I deploy it in Shiny.

I also attempted downloading an older version of rgdal and found a list of archived versions here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/

When I put in `version = "1.2-15"` the download worked, but it required me to download Rtools (Rtools34) to install that version.

After Rtools and rgdal (1.2-15) finished installing, I published the Shiny app again, but it still doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
counties <- readOGR(dsn = "./gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.json", layer= "gz_2010_us_050_00_20m")
```

Update:
After downgrading to 1.2-15, and changing my code to `layer = "OGRGeoJSON"`, the app deployed successfully!

Answer (score 1):

This error can come up if you recently installed GDAL which is the program that the `readOGR` function is calling. GDAL 2.2.0 [introduced an API change to how it reads GeoJSON files](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.2.0-News). You can check your GDAL version by running `gdalinfo --version` in terminal.

If this is the case, you can adjust this part of your code from

```
maine <- readOGR(dsn="/data/maine.geojson", layer="OGRGeoJSON")
```

to

```
maine <- readOGR(dsn="/data/maine.geojson", layer="maine")
```

Then I suspect it will work.

Comment: I reinstalled the rgdal package and tried your fix, still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you check which version of GDAL is installed on your computer - in terminal `gdalinfo --version` and which version of GDAL R is by typing in your R console `rgdal::getGDALVersionInfo()`

Comment: I don't have GDAL installed, only the rgdal package which is 2.2.0.

Comment: Installing GDAL using this link did not fix the issue: http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1800-x64-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6/gdal-202-1800-x64-core.msi

Comment: I'm attempting to install an older version of rgdal using: `require(devtools)
install_version("rgdal", version = "2.1.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`. I am getting an error saying version 2.1.0 does not exist

Comment: Omitting the layer name entirely may be necessary.